# Для чего нужен Docker Executor в GitLab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, ci-cd

Доброго времени суток.

Для чего нужно использовать `docker` executor в git lab runner  если можно использовать `shell` executor. Если вы когда-либо использовали `GitLab CI` то на этапе регистрации `gitlab-runner` вас просят выбрать тип `gitlab-runner` из возможных:

> Enter an executor: `ssh`, `virtualbox`, `docker`, `docker-ssh`, `parallels`, `shell`, `kubernetes`, `custom`:

так как мой проект я поднимаю в docker то я логично выбираю `docker` executor, но ведь я могу выбрать `shell` и прописать необходимые команды в нём. Тогда какой смысл в `docker` executor ?

Comment: shell executor не изолирован от остальной системы, а значит запускаемые в нём проекты имеют возможность напакостить

Comment: @andreymal Он будет изолирован, если сам runner находится в контейнере.

Comment: @user7860670 это если не забыть его изолировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker executor позволяет выбрать контейнер, который будет использоваться для выполнения команд сборки. В том числе поддерживается сценарий docker-in-docker для сборки образов. см https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html